# Image URL Conflict after migration

Tags: wordpress, image, url

My site sees a conflict with the URL. Everything has moved to new https url, but the logo / images are still pointing to the old http url. I already used Search and replace url plugin, such as "Better Search Replace", "Search and Replace" and "WP Migrate DB" but it seems no result after all.

Has anyone run into the same problem? I kinda need help with this.

Comment: Easy and fast fix: 1. Update permalinks in Settings->Permalinks, press save. 2. Install SSL Insecure Content Fixer plugin and activate, configure due to your site.
https://uk.wordpress.org/plugins/ssl-insecure-content-fixer/

Comment: Thanks I will try to use the said plugin ..

Answer (score 0):

Kindly migrate your database through Wp migrate db correctly.
in the first field add http:// or https:// and remove the last /
and in the second field write your correct folder path.

Comment: if the issue didn't resolve then do let me know i will help you.

Comment: Yes Sir.. I will also try the Wp migrate db plugin. Thank you.